# Evenly-sized buttons according to content of largest button

Tags: wpf, xaml, layout

Imagine I have two WPF buttons on a window, with content as follows:

```
<Button>OK</Button>
<Button>Cancel</Button>
```

I want these buttons to be the same width, however in a scenario where the `Content` is bound to a localised value for a given user's language, I don't know how wide the buttons need to be to accommodate the new content.

How might I apply a minimum width to these buttons, such that the width of the widest one (according to content) is effectively used as the `MinWidth` of both, thus keeping them uniform?

Or to put it another way: I don't want the buttons to be the width of their container (unless using a container in a clever way is the answer to my problem), and I don't want them each to just size to their own content because that will make them different sizes. I want something in-between. The one with the largest content to size to display it's content, and all others to size to that same width, so the widths are all equal.

I expect the answer lies in putting them in some sort of container. I know I could use a `Grid` and let them fill grid "cells", but the point is I don't want them to be *too* wide, either. I know I could have some code-behind that runs on the `Content_Changed` event of the buttons and sets the minwidth to that of the widest button, but I'm interested in a pure-xaml method. It might be I need to create a custom control extending `ItemsControl` that rusn code-behind when new items are added or re-sized and applies the width of the widest item as the `MinWidth` of all the other items.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: So you are saying you don't want to use the <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" /> and set the Buttons Width="Auto"?

Comment: I don't want the buttons to be the width of their container (unless using a container in a clever way is the answer to my problem), and I don't want them to size to their content because that will make them different sizes. I want something in-between. The one with the largest content to size to display it's content, and all others to size to that same amount, so the widths are all equal.

Comment: So then i guess your buttons are all scattered on your view, because if not, and their all grouped, then the ColumnDefinition will do the trick. If their all scattered, i would also like to know a good solution for your problem. =)

Comment: No, they were in a horizontally-aligned stackpanel, in a classic "OK", "Cancel" design. I think H.B.'s answer below (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6249946/wpf-evenly-sized-buttons-according-to-content-of-largest-button/6250568#6250568) actually is what you said, I just hadn't really grasped properly from your comment what you meant. :)

Comment: @Willem `<ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>` needed not `"Auto"`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
Use UniformGrid

<UniformGrid HorizontalAlignment="Right" Rows="1" Columns="2">
  <Button Content="Ok" Grid.Column="0"/>
  <Button Content="Cancel" Grid.Column="1"/>
</UniformGrid>
```

Comment: This answer has the advantage of allowing you to set Visibility = "Collapsed" for buttons that you don't want and the entire cell disappears - doing that with a SharedSizeGroup grid leaves you with a hole, which might not be what you want.

Plus its terser!

Comment: `Grid.Column` and `Grid.Row` are ignored by `UniformGrid`, controls are added in order of declaration in Xaml.

Answer (score 25):

The Grid

```xml
  <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="true">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="A"/>
        <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="A"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.Children>
        <Button Grid.Column="0" Content="OK"/>
        <Button Grid.Column="1" Content="Cancel"/>
    </Grid.Children>
  </Grid>
```

This can be broken up, you just need to set the [`IsSharedSizeScope`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.issharedsizescope.aspx) on a common ancestor, e.g.:

```
    <StackPanel Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="true">
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Right">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="A"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.Children>
                <Button Grid.Column="0" Content="OK"/>
            </Grid.Children>
        </Grid>
        <!-- ... -->
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="A"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.Children>
                <Button Grid.Column="0" Content="Cancel"/>
            </Grid.Children>
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
```

To prevent the buttons from becoming too large change the `HorizontalAlignment` of the Grid to something else than `Stretch` or set a `MaxWidth`.

Comment: The way you showed which using SharedSizeGroup I think is more useful than the answer accepted by the author.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I like using a wrap panel for this type of scenario. When it's loaded I get the max width from all children using `linq`. (assuming children are all buttons)

**xaml**

```
<WrapPanel Name="WP_ButtonSelections" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Loaded="WP_ButtonSelections_Loaded"></WrapPanel>
```

**cs**

```
WP_ButtonSelections.Children.Add(new Button() { Content = "Hello" });
WP_ButtonSelections.Children.Add(new Button() { Content = "Hello World" });


private void WP_ButtonSelections_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   double maxWidth = WP_ButtonSelections.Children.OfType<FrameworkElement>().Max(elm => elm.ActualWidth);
   WP_ButtonSelections.Children.OfType<FrameworkElement>().ToList().ForEach(elm => elm.Width = maxWidth);
}
```

I needed a programmatic solution. This requires the loaded event because programmatically added buttons wont have an `ActualWidth` defined upon calling  `WP_ButtonSelections.Children.Add()`. This solution *should* work with xaml defined buttons, or a mixture of both xaml and programmatic.